# Howto MongoDB update / $set entire subdocument

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

In my MongoDB, I have Document1, as seen below. I want to reach into the "main.accounts" (and later, "main.entries") document, and update ($set) an entire sub-document in a "content' array. Wrt sub-documents, so far, I've been able to add and remove a document to and from a "content" sub-array. But in this case, I want to update the entire document; Not just update ($set) one property in a matched document.

Below, I've tried using just a $set, a $set with $elemMatch. And I've also tried findAndModify, but to no avail. Of course, I've i) RTFM, looked all around ii) the internet and iii) SO, to find a solution. Has anyone been able to update an entire document in this manner?

Thanks 
Tim

**Update try 1** - this is the only update that works, but sets the entire "content" array to the hash … { "fu" : "bar" }

```
    db.bookkeeping.update(
      { 
        owner : "twashing@gmail.com", 
        "content.content.tag" : "account", 
        "content.content.id" : "one" 
      }, 
      { $set : { "content.$.content" : { "fu" : "bar" } } } 
    )
```

**Update try 2** - this doesn't fail, but doesn't update the document in question

```
    db.bookkeeping.update(
      { 
        owner : "fu", 
        thing : { $elemMatch : { "content.content.tag" : "account", "content.content.id" : "one"  } }
      }, 
      { $set : { "thing" : { "fu" : "bar" } } } 
    )
```

**Update try 3** - this doesn't fail, but doesn't update the document in question

```
    db.bookkeeping.update(
      { thing : { $elemMatch : { owner : "fu" ,  "content.content.tag" : "account", "content.content.id" : "one" } } }, 
      { $set : { "thing.content.content.$" :  { "fu" : "bar" } } }
    )
```

**Document1**

```
    {
            "_id" : "fid",
            "content" : [
                    {
                            "content" : [
                                    {
                                            "id" : "one",
                                            "tag" : "account"
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "id" : "two",
                                            "tag" : "account"
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "id" : "three",
                                            "tag" : "account"
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "id" : "four",
                                            "tag" : "account"
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "id" : "five",
                                            "tag" : "account"
                                    }

                            ],
                            "id" : "main.accounts",
                            "tag" : "accounts"
                    },
                    {
                            "tag" : "journals",
                            "id" : "main.journals",
                            "content" : [
                                    {
                                            "tag" : "journal",
                                            "id" : "generalledger",
                                            "name" : "generalledger",
                                            "type" : "",
                                            "balance" : "",
                                            "content" : [
                                                    {
                                                            "tag" : "entries",
                                                            "id" : "main.entries",
                                                            "content" : [ ]
                                                    }
                                            ]
                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            ],
            "owner" : "fu",
            "tag" : "fubar"
    }
```

Comment: which document do you want to update.  confused by the question.  why do you keep talking about update ($set)?

Comment: I'm trying to update the object: `{ "id" : "one", "tag" : "account" }`. And I mean that functionally, I want to update said document. And I'm trying to do that using the $set operator. Hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use positional operator `$` for updating second level of array.(Array inside array)

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341151/mongodb-update-deep-array) might help you

Comment: Hey Ravi, thanks for the insights on the `$` positional operator. But wrt updating a value, that link only shows updating a single member of a hash, like ... **name : "Smells Like Teen Spirit!!"**. I haven't been able to update the entire document, like `{ name : "Smells Like Teen Spirit!!", order : 1, duration : 301 }`. Can I do that with **$set** ? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I solved this one by hard-coding array positions in the query and update path. And that link tipped me off to the solution, so thanks. So I have something like the following (Clojure code calling to mongodb): `(mc/update "bookkeeping"  { :owner uname "content.1.content.0.content.0.content.tag" "entry" } { mop/$set  { :content.1.content.0.content.0.content.$ entry } } )`. Is it me, or are the update semantics for MongoDB really convoluted and poorly explained? Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can't do that in the mongoDB console without some programming logic, because you use multiple arrays in your structure and you are searching for an sub document (content[documents]) (main.accounts and main.entries) in an array, which will return the same root document, but in that return value you can not know on what position in the content array was your criteria. Because of that you can't inject your new values at the right position.

If possible I would recommend to restructure the document to avoid so many nested arrays(content->content->content->content), especially if you plan to do some updates on subset of them. After all this is NoSQL so its' fine to have some redundant data in your design, as long that makes your life easier and your code more clean.

Comment: Right. So one of the things that this exercise has taught me is that NoSQL is probably not good for anything other than a very flat structure. Looks like it shouldn't be any deeper than 1 level. I don't accept that in any modern data service, it should be difficult to update something at any location in the document. Furthermore, [JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (and even [XQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery)) has had this solved for quite a while now. So no, I'm not inclined to restructure my documents to appease MongoDB limitations.

Comment: @golja Isn't that the point of NoSQL document driven data structures? Being able to nest things so we don't have to have collections all over the place? I agree with nutritioustim