# Update deeply nested array element in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update an inner element `state` field in a mongodb collection, I have given below the collection and my mongodb update statement.

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("561b4c83e3603fcd1badaeb3"),
        "continent" : "Asia",
        "countries" : [
            {
                "country" : "India",
                "_id" : ObjectId("561b83c3626fca4a23c0131f"),
                "states" : [
                    {
                        "state" : "Kerala"
                    }
                 ........ many other states
                ]
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

I used this mongodb query.

```
    db.places.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("561b4c83e3603fcd1badaeb3"), "countries.states.state": "Kerala" },{ $set: { "country.$.states.$.state": "Tamilnad" } } );
```

Expected result

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("561b4c83e3603fcd1badaeb3"),
        "continent" : "Asia",
        "countries" : [
            {
                "country" : "India",
                "_id" : ObjectId("561b83c3626fca4a23c0131f"),
                "states" : [
                    {
                        "state" : "Goa"
                    }
                 ........ many other states
                ]
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Update Deep Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341151/mongodb-update-deep-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use $addToSet to add an element in array

> db.collection.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("561b4c83e3603fcd1badaeb3"), "countries.states.state": "Kerala" },{ $addToSet: { "countries.$.states": {"state":"Goa"} } } )

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Mongo doesn't support multiple positional operators. You'll have to do it with js using mongo's [foreach method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)

```
db.coll.find().forEach(function( doc ) {
  //supposing only one country will match the query 
    var statesCount = doc.countries[0].states.length;
    for(var i=0; i<statesCount; i++){
        if(doc.countries[0].states[i].state == "Kerala"){
            doc.countries[0].states[i].state = "Goa";
        }       
    }
    db.coll.save(doc);
});
```

**Another option:** This feature should be fixed in version 3.5.12, see [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831)

hope this will help someone.