# Updating deep data array on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to push an object to the  deeply nested `checklist` array below :

```js
{
 // User
  _id : "id",
  days : [
     {
       _id : "id"
       day : "6",
       tasks: [
          {
            _id : "id",
            name : "todo"
            types : {
              checklist : [] // i want to push objects here
              notes : []
            }
          },
          ....
       ]
     },
     ....
  ]
}
```

Here is what i have tried but failed... my guess is that the `$` operator shouldn't be at that position:

```js
User.update({_id : user._id , "days.tasks.name": 'todo' } ,{ $push : { 'days.tasks.$.types.checklist' : { data : 'hello World' } }})
```

Comment: You can see here at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341151/mongodb-update-deep-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341151/mongodb-update-deep-array)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can re-design your DB and made some child Model, ref with ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which basically looking for the index of the specific task using the unique id:

```js
router.patch('/user/updatetask', auth , async (req,res)=>{
    const user = req.user
    const dayIndex = user.days.indexOf(user.days.find(day => day.day == req.body.day))
    const taskIndex = user.days[dayIndex].tasks.indexOf(user.days[dayIndex].tasks.find(task => task._id == req.body.task_id))
    var obj = {}
        obj[`days.${dayIndex}.tasks.${taskIndex}.types.checklist`] = 'no'
    try {

        await  User.updateOne({_id : user._id } ,{ $push :obj})
        res.status(201).send(user)
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```